# Reassign self in init

Tags: python

I have a class that has lookup dict in the class body, which I store all the instances and with some key.

When I instantiate the instances I don't hold them in any variable or external dict, I store them in this lookup dict.

When somehow I instantiate an instance that is already in the dict, I reassign it to the one in the dict and update it, using it's new and old value in some other function.

I wonder if this is a good practice? Or I should refactor and make it have a external dict that hold the instances.

Is there any PEP guide to this kind of behavior?

Example:

```
class MyClass:
    all_instances = {}  # this dictionary is in local space and it's clear that
                        # the only interaction is with MyClass

    def __init__(self, unique_id, x, y, z):
        if unique_id not in MyClass.all_instances:
            self.unique_id = unique_id
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.z = z
            MyClass.all_instances[unique_id] = self
        else:
            self = MyClass.all_instances[unique_id]
            self.update(x, y, z)

    def update(self, new_x, new_y, new_z):
        self.x = self.do_something_with(self.x, new_x)
        self.y = self.do_something_with(self.y, new_y)
        self.z = self.do_something_with(self.z, new_z)

    @staticmethod
    def do_something_with(old_value, new_value):
        # do something with old value and new and return some value
        value = (old_value + new_value) / 2  # more complicated than tht
        return value


while True:
    for id in get_ids():  # fetch ids from some database
        x, y, z = get_values(id)  # fetch values from some other database
        MyClass(id, x, y, z)
```

The databases where I get the ids and values is changing every time, so I can't know for sure if I'll get the ones I have already instantiate, or the values will be different.

The way I see, is that all the functionality of the class happens within itself, no need to have dictionaries laying around, making it unclear where they are interacting with any other part of the code.

This is how I would normally do, without reassigning it:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def update(self, new_x, new_y, new_z):
        self.x = self.do_something_with(self.x, new_x)
        self.y = self.do_something_with(self.y, new_y)
        self.z = self.do_something_with(self.z, new_z)

    @staticmethod
    def do_something_with(old_value, new_value):
        # do something with old value and new and return some value
        value = (old_value + new_value) / 2  # more complicated than tht
        return value

all_instances = {}  # this dictionary is now in global space
                    # and it's unclear if the only interaction is with MyClass
while True:
    for id in get_ids():  # fetch ids from some database
        x, y, z = get_values(id)  # fetch values from some other database
        if id not in all_instances:
            all_instances[id] = MyClass(x, y, z)
        else:
            all_instances[id].update(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Reassigning `self` doesn't do anything. It's the same as if you did `foo = ...`

Comment: In my example it does, if you don't do it it will raise an AttributeError, because x, y and z where not assigned.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Python doesn't treat self as a special case. There's no error whether you use `foo =` or `self =` because all_instances contains initialized MyClass objects.

Comment: You'd also need to change the next line to use `foo.update`, but I thought that was obvious. Assigning self doesn't do anything special.

Comment: Ah I know what you mean, `self` is not special keyword or anything, but what I mean is that in my case if I don't do `self = MyClass.all_instances[unique_id]` I can't get the values that are already stored in the dict. Of course I could do `MyClass.all_instances[unique_id].update(x, y, z)`, but that seem ugly.

Comment: Just replace self with some other variable name on those two lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've got here is a singleton-like pattern.  (I say singleton-like because you don't actually have just one instance, but a set of instances keyed off a couple of parameters).  There are [lots of reason why singletons (and global data in general) are a bad idea](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil), so I'd vote for the external registry.

However, if after thinking about it a bit, if you decide that you *do* want to use an "internal" registry, you can do that using [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).

```
class MyClass(object):

    all_instances = {}

    def __new__(cls, unique_id, x, y, z):
        instance = cls.all_instances.get(unique_id)
        if instance is not None:
            instance.is_initialized = True
        else:
            instance = super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls, unique_id, x, y, z)
            instance.is_initialized = False
        return instance

    def __init__(self, unique_id, x, y, z):
        if self.is_initialized:
            return
        # Do initialization here.
```

Notice how `__new__` is used to change how object creation happens.  If we already have a registered object, we return it rather than creating a new object -- Otherwise, we call `__new__` on the super class (`object`) which gives us a new (uninitialized) instance of `MyClass`.  After `__new__` has been called (and assuming that it returns an instance of `MyClass`), `__init__` will be called.  This can lead to `__init__` being called multiple times for the same object (that's what all the `is_initialized` business is about.

The `is_initialized` bit is optional -- I'm assuming you don't want to reset `x`, `y`, `z`, etc.  But if you do, you can leave it off.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I find this to be way more complicated than what I have, the line `super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls, unique_id, x, y, z)` is very unclear.

Comment: Would it help if you just did `object.__new__(cls, unique_id, x, y, z)` -- Because that's really all I've done here.   Note that your code has a couple problems.  Say you do `a = MyClass('Foo', ...)` then later you do `b = MyClass('Foo', ...)`.  You're probably expecting `a` and `b` to be interchangeable at this point -- But they're not.  If you decide to modify an attribute of `b` (`b.x = 12`), you won't see that change reflected in `a` since they're still different objects.  You can't reset `self` in a method like that.

Comment: My concern is that storing it externally in a dict will make unclear if anything else will mess with the content of the dict, the way I see, my 'singleton' and a global dict behave in the same way, I have just one place where the data is stored, but in one of them it's nested inside a class, while in the other is in the global namespace, any function can access `all_instances`, while to access it inside MyClass you have to use MyClass.all_instances, which is more obvious that they are FROM that class, while in the global can mean any class instance.

Comment: @f.rodrigues You can use MyClass.all_instances that way without reassigning self.  You can't reassign self to prevent 'MyClass(...)` from creating and returning a new MyClass object each time it's called.

Comment: You mean: `for id in get_ids():
    x, y, z = get_values(id)
    if id not in MyClass.all_instances:
        MyClass.all_instances[id] = MyClass(x, y, z)
    else:
        MyClass.all_instances[id].update(x, y, z)`

That seems reasonable. I haven't thought of that. Seem way more explicit than having it in global.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = {}
class abc:
     def __init__(self) : pass
     def update(self,_id,old,new):
          result["res:"+str(_id)] = (old + new)/2.0
     def clean(self,command):
          for e in result.keys():
               if e.startswith("res:"):
                    if command == "to_zero": result[e]= 0
                    elif command == "del": del result[e]
     def read(self,_id):
          if "res:"+_id in result.keys() : return _id,result["res:"+_id]



result["fun"] = abc()

result['fun'].update("hello",8,3)
print result["fun"].read("hello")

>>> 
('hello', 5.5)
>>>
```

Please give me a lot - for waste user time. Maybe `Si tacuisses, philosophus mansisses`